# PyQGIS: Iterate extract by location over features

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Using python script editor in QGIS, I'm trying to create code that extracts features by the location of an input layer for each feature in the intersect layer. The diagram below explains what I mean

[image]

My code below iterates over the features in the intersect layer and runs extract by location each time, but everything that touches any feature in the intersect layer is included in each output.

```
input_shp = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('shp_1')[0]

intersect_shp = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('shp_2')[0]

features = intersect_shp.getFeatures()

for feature in features:
    intersect = processing.run("native:extractbylocation", {'INPUT': input_shp,'PREDICATE':[6],\
    'INTERSECT': intersect_shp, 'OUTPUT':QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT})['OUTPUT']
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(intersect)
```

Comment: Intersect everything once then extract by attributes, probably alot faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following. You need to iteratively select each feature in your intersect layer and run the algorithm on selected features only.

```py
input_shp = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('shp_1')[0]
intersect_shp = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('shp_2')[0]

for feature in intersect_shp.getFeatures():
    intersect_shp.selectByIds([feature.id()])
    processing.runAndLoadResults("native:extractbylocation",
    {'INPUT':input_shp,
    'PREDICATE':[6],
    'INTERSECT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(intersect_shp.id(),
    selectedFeaturesOnly=True,
    featureLimit=-1,
    geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

intersect_shp.selectByIds([])
```